Docker, "The scheduler does not appear to be running" and "The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled." in Airflow
I am new to Docker and just started learning it, so I have stumbled into this problem that I do not know how to solve.
The airflow page shows an empty list of dags. When I check the Docker desktop app after running the "docker-compose up —d" command, all containers get initialized, but when I check the scheduler logs, they are empty.
also in the webserver and scheduler logs for some reason, I don't see the dependencies from requirments.txt getting installed
I don't know what other details to add, but I will add my code.
Thank you in advance


docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - confluent
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      -  "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', 'nc -z localhost 9092']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.4.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081/" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.4.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
      schema-registry:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONFLIENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      PORT: 9021
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9021/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  webserver:
    image: apache/airflow
    command: webserver
    entrypoint: ['/opt/airflow/script/entrypoint.sh']
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Sequential
      - AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALECHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgresql:5432/airflow
      - AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_SECRET_KEY=secret_key
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./script/entrypoint.sh:/opt/airflow/script/entrypoint.sh
      - ./requirments.txt:/opt/airflow/requirments.txt
    ports:
      -  "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD-SHELL', "[ -f /opt/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - confluent
  scheduler:
    image:  apache/airflow
    depends_on:
      webserver:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./script/entrypoint.sh:/opt/airflow/scripts/encryption.sh
    - ./requirements.txt:/opt/airflow/requirements.txt
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Sequential
      - AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgresql:5432/airflow
      - AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_SECRET_KEY=secret_key
    command: bash -c "pip install -r ./requirements.txt && airflow db upgrade && airflow scheduler"
    networks:
      - confluent
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    logging:
        options:
          max-size: 10m
          max-file: "3"
    networks:
    -  confluent
  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    networks:
      - confluent
  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    networks:
      - confluent

  cassandra_db:
    image: cassandra:latest
    container_name: cassandra
    hostname: cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    environment:
      - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=512M
      - HEAP_NEWSIZE=100M
      - CASSANDRA_USERNAME=cassandra
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra
    networks:
      - confluent
networks:
  confluent:
    enter code here

kafka_stream.py "file inside dags directory":
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import uuid

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airscholar',
        'start_date': datetime(2025, 8, 3, 10, 00)
}
def get_data():
    import requests
    res = requests.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').json()
    return res['results'][0]

def format_data(res):
    data = {}
    location = res['location']
    data['id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    data['first_name'] = res['name']['first']
    data['last_name'] = res['name']['last']
    data['gender'] = res['gender']
    data['address'] = f"{str(location['street']['number'])} {location['street']['name']}, " \
                      f"{location['city']}, {location['state']}, {location['country']}"
    data['post_code'] = location['postcode']
    data['email'] = res['email']
    data['username'] = res['login']['username']
    data['dob'] = res['dob']['date']
    data['registered_date'] = res['registered']['date']
    data['phone'] = res['phone']
    data['picture'] = res['picture']['medium']

    return data

def stream_data():
    import json
    from kafka import KafkaProducer
    import time

    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['broker:29092'], max_block_ms=5000)
    curr_time = time.time()

    while True:
        if time.time() > curr_time + 60:
            break
        try:
            res = get_data()
            res = format_data(res)
            producer.send('users_created', json.dumps(res).encode('utf-8'))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'An error occured: {e}')
            continue



with DAG('user_automation',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='@daily',
         catchup=False) as dag:

    streaming_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='stream_data_from_api',
        python_callable=stream_data
    )

entrypoint.sh "inside script directory":
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -e "/opt/airflow/requirements.txt" ]; then
  $(command python) pip install --upgrade pip
  $(command -v pip) install --user -r requirements.txt
fi

if [ ! -f "/opt/airflow/airflow.db" ]; then
  airflow db init && \
  airflow users create \
    --username admin \
    --firstname admin \
    --lastname admin \
    --role Admin \
    --email admin@example.com \
    --password admin
fi

$(command -v airflow) db upgrade

exec airflow webserver

PS: I am new to this technology so please if you need any missing information don't hesitate to ask it.
